# PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "idRoom" of relation "Bed" violates not-null constraint

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i'm working using spring boot , and i'm trying to add beds to database(postgresql) but i'm facing this error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "idRoom" of relation "Bed" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (34, sxxkskskso, null).
```

**BedRequest**

```
package com.bezkoder.springjwt.pojo;

public class BedRequest {


    public Long idBed;


    public String bedNumber;

    public long roomId;


    public Long getIdBed() {
        return idBed;
    }

    public void setIdBed(Long idBed) {
        this.idBed = idBed;
    }

    public String getBedNumber() {
        return bedNumber;
    }

    public void setBedNumber(String bedNumber) {
        this.bedNumber = bedNumber;
    }

    public long getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public void setRoomId(long roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
    }
}
```

**Bed**

```
package com.bezkoder.springjwt.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Bed {




    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long idBed;

    private String bedNumber ;


    @ManyToOne
            (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "idRoom")
    private Room room;


    public Bed(Long idBed, String bedNumber) {
        this.idBed = idBed;
        this.bedNumber = bedNumber;

    }

    public Bed() {

    }




    public String getBedNumber() {
        return bedNumber;
    }

    public void setBedNumber(String bedNumber) {
        this.bedNumber = bedNumber;
    }
    public Long getIdBed() {
        return idBed;
    }

    public void setIdBed(Long idBed) {
        this.idBed = idBed;
    }

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }
}
```

**Room Class**

```
  @Override
    public Bed addBed(BedRequest bedRequest) {
        Room room = roomRepository.findByIdRoom(bedRequest.roomId);

        Bed bed = new Bed();

        bed.setBedNumber(bedRequest.bedNumber);
        bed.setRoom(room);
        return bedRepository.save(bed);
    }
```

**BedController class**

```
   @PostMapping("/createBed")
    public Bed AddBed(@RequestBody BedRequest bedRequest){



        return bedService.addBed(bedRequest);
    }
```

**Debug Result**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-05-30T18:01:33.500+0000",
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Required request body is missing: public com.bezkoder.springjwt.models.Bed com.bezkoder.springjwt.controllers.BedController.AddBed(com.bezkoder.springjwt.pojo.BedRequest)",
  "path": "/api/auth/bed/createBed"
}
```

I really don't understand what is happening underneath here, if someone able to help me with this? I've looked in the internet for answers but nothing's worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in the mapping, please check your Room class and put this :

```
@OneToMany
        (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "room")
private Set<Bed> beds;
```

put this in your serviceImpl you cand add Bed by id:

```
 @Override
    public Bed addBed(BedRequest bedRequest) {
        Room room = roomRepository.findByIdRoom(bedRequest.idRoom);

        Bed bed = new Bed();

        bed.setBedNumber(bedRequest.bedNumber);
        bed.setRoom(room);
        return bedRepository.save(bed);
    }
```

and this in BedController :

```
 @PostMapping("/createBed")
    public ResponseEntity<?> AddBed(@RequestBody BedRequest bedRequest){

        bedService.addBed(bedRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Bed registered successfully!"));

    }
```